# Android.content.ActivityNotFoundException on SGS 2 with Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I have an app which enables the user to insert an event in his devices's default calendar

I am starting the activity to insert the event into the default calendar with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true)
                .putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=YEARLY;")
                .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_FREE)
                .putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
                .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description)
                .putExtra(Events.HAS_ALARM, false);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

According to the SDK docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert , this is the correct and recommended way to do this in Android 4 and above.

This works nicely in my old Samsung Galaxy S with Android 4.0.3 (a barebone ICS Custom ROM  by TEAMSGS for the old Samsung Galaxy S).

However, after updating the Samsung Galaxy S2 of a friend to Samsung Stock Android 4.0.4, this code will cause an ActivityNotFound Exception:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT dat=content:xxxxx (has
>   extras) }  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1535)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1387)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3195)  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3302)  at
>   com.radlmaier.heiligenkalender.rk.OptionsMenuHandler.onOptionsItemSelected(OptionsMenuHandler.java:119)
>   at
>   com.radlmaier.heiligenkalender.rk.Main.onOptionsItemSelected(Main.java:994)
>   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2507)  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:979)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:178)
>   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292) 
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1181) 
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2709) 
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3464)  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any ideas why this is failing although I am using the exact way as recommended by the SDK docs?

This is really bothering me, because I don't know if there are other Android 4 devices which don't seem to comply with the SDK docs...

Comment: have you tried on other devices that without custom UI? Google Calendar now is an app out of Google Framework, its on Play Store, you can try to install it on your S2 first. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar

Comment: I was assuming that the Stock Calendar app is installed of all Android distributions and therefore this code should always work on all devices? No matter, if Samsung is shipping Android with their customized Calendar app, which may indeed need a different intent? Similiarly like a user can install a different SMS app, but can not remove the Stock SMS app without having a rooted device? My goal is code which will work on all device (to avoid Android Version fragmentation)

Comment: It is possible that they'r using different intents. Cuz your Galaxy S (running on 3rd party ROM without TouchWiz UI, I presume?) is running correctly but for S2, android can't find the activity. So, just to narrow the problem, could you try this code on other devices with pure android?

Comment: @ss1271: Unfortunately, I don't have access to any other Android 4+ devices.

Comment: A workaround might be, instead of using an explicit intent, using an implicit intent. But I don't know which intent/intent filters to use?

Comment: @ss1271: The 3rd party ROM I am using is "Android like Android is meant to be" [quote from the devlopers] from TEAMSGS (found at xda-developers), without any customisations like TouchWiz or Sense UI.